# Having problems with setTimeout & onload

Tags: javascript, php, settimeout

I am trying to check if a cookie exists, and if not, load a file with a 3 second delay.

I've checked and the php bit works ok, but the page doesn't load.

This is in the main index.php file and the popup.php is a modal newsletter sign up popup.

Any help much appreciated.

```
    <div id="newsletter"></div>

    <?php   
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['somecookie']))  {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $("#newsletter").load("inserts/popup.php");
        },3000);
    });
    </script>

    <?php
    } else {} 
    ?>
```

Comment: Is the cookie already set in your browser? Any errors in the browser console? Do you see the request for `inserts/popup` in the devtools network tab? Does it work if you remove the cookie condition?

Comment: Yes - with a status 200

Comment: Does the response look like what you'd expect?

Comment: Doesn't work either if I remove the condition :-/

Comment: I haven't a clue what I'm supposed to expect lol

Comment: What's the current behaviour?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Rohan - nothing happens. index.php loads ok but no popup

Comment: If I load popup.php using a php include inside the cookie condition everything works fine. I am just trying to find a way to delay that bit rather than the whole page

Comment: If you open the network tab in the devtools and click on the `inserts/popup` request, then select either the 'preview' tab or the 'response' tab, does it look like what you would expect?

Comment: Ray - I got annoyed and deleted index.php off the server, double checked I hadn't done anything silly and then uploaded the index.php again. And bugger me it decided to work! Thank you for your time which hasn't been wasted - you've actually educated me about the network and console screens and how they are helpful when I get stuck on something else! :-)

Comment: Is the ready, and timeout triggering ok. Could be worth putting a alert('test'); in the timeout to make sure that's triggering. Also you may need to out the full URL into the load function

Answer (score 0):

Is the path where file placed is correct? Have you privileges to access that folder and file?

If you are on Linux, try

```
sudo chmod -R 777 *Your path goes here*
```

Comment: devtools network shows file loaded ok. No console errors.

Comment: @AlexPetrov that would delay the entire initial page load, wouldn't it?

Comment: Alright, as if I understand it correctly, you want to just delay your function to execute in 3 seconds? So in this cases you can try standard sleep() php function.

Comment: In documentation it says that "The sleep() function in PHP is an inbuilt function which is used to delay the execution of THE CURRENT SCRIPT for a specified number of seconds."

Comment: So anyway it worth to try

Comment: @AlexPetrov She's trying to delay it client side, not server side.